# Error 11 error LNK2005: "class cv::Mat imageOutput" (?imageOutput@@3VMat@cv@@A) already defined in MyForm.obj

Tags: c++, winforms, opencv, user-interface, command-line-interface

I'm pretty new to C++/CLI. I've developed my code in "normal" C++ and now I'm just trying to wrap a GUI around it.

My GUI consists of two forms. The main one (Form1) has most of my OpenCV code and works and compiles fine until I attempt to create a cv::Mat object in Form2. When compiling the linker brings up the following error:

Error   11  error LNK2005: "class cv::Mat ProgramWrapper::imageOutput" (?imageOutput@ProgramWrapper@@3VMat@cv@@A) already defined in MyForm.obj

Error   12  error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is looking for an answer and not getting any luck with externs etc I finally found a solution that worked for me.

Just put your variables in each form in a nameless namespace. Eg.:

```
namespace {
cv::Mat image
}
```